# How obtain coordinates of pixels within bwboundaries in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Suppose I have an image

[image]

and then I use the code below

```
I=imread("image.bmp");
imshow(I); hold on; [B,L,N] = bwboundaries(I);
for k=1:length(B),
    boundary = B{k};
    plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1),'.r')
end
```

The boundaries then look like

[image]

However, I don't just want the x,y coordinates of each pixel ON the boundaries. I also want the x,y coordinates of each pixel INSIDE the boundaries also

Is there a way to do this in Matlab?

EDIT: I want to store the row/column numbers for each object in separate matrices. So matrix A1 should store the row/column numbers for the white pixels in the big object, matrix A2 should store the row/column numbers for the white pixels in the circular object

Comment: I think `boundary = B{k};` only contains the row,column numbers of the boundary points (the ones in red), and NOT ALL pixels within the boundaries

Comment: I want to store the row/column numbers for each object in separate matrices. So matrix `A1` should store the row/column numbers for the white pixels in the big object, matrix `A2` should store the row/column numbers for the white pixels in the circular object

Comment: mmm... [`bwconncomp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html)? It returns linear indices, but that's easy enough to fix.

Comment: `bwconncomp` and then what?